# Windows 10 notepad stops responding while replacing text with the same text using Wrap around and Replace All

Tags: windows, notepad

I was trying to replace some text, but I don't change the text I wanted to replace it with (paste the same text in Find what: and Replace with:) and while replacing text using Wrap around option and clicking Replace All, text I was trying to replace started blinking and notepad stops responding. e.g. replacing "text1" to "text1".
There is also a problem when there is only one specific character in a file, when I am trying to replace that character (again using Wrap around option and clicking Replace All) by one or more of the same characters and maybe more other characters e.g. "a" by "au" or by "ua" or by "aa" in a file with only one "a" in it e.g. "I am writing..." **(** everything without quotation marks **)**, it starts to replace this character for some time and stops, also responding.

**I would like to fucus more at the first problem as it can happen more often, when changing similar text.**

Some of the system informations:
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H1
OS build    19043.1165
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0

**What (can be/is) the issue?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've turned on wrap-around for the search/replace, and ensured that what you're searching for will continue to be found. Using your first example, suppose that the first line of your file is

```
text
```

and you search for `text` and replace it with `text1`. The first thing it will find is that first line, and will change it to

```
text1
```

and continue with the rest of the file. Now, when it reaches the end, it will wrap back to the beginning of the file, where it will find `text` in the `text1`, which it will replace, making the first line of the file

```
text11
```

and continuing through the rest of the file. When it reaches the end, since you have wrap-around on, it will wrap back to the beginning of the file, where it will find `text` in the `text11`, which it will replace...

Comment: But if it will stop only if it doesn't find anything in one iteration throught the file, then **if text occur more than once in a file, it will not stop, but it's not like that.** Also I want to focus on the first problem, when I am replacing similar text, I paste the same text in *Find what:* and *Replace with:*, when there is only one such text in file, it will freeze. For example replacing case of variable/id/class name that occurs only once in a file without selecting *Match case* or clicking enter before changing text in *Replace with:*. Neither of this problems occurs in notepad++.

Comment: My question at the end of the post is: **What (can be/is) the issue?**. I know already that stopping after no match is found in one iteration (which is, I think, what you wanted to point out) is not the issue because it works fine when replacing e.g. *text* with *text1* if *text* occurs more than once in a file. I think that wrap around should wrap throught end of the file only once and stop where it started for *Replace All*, same as without *Wrap around*. I deleted the first comment because it took more than five minutes to edit it.